# Accessing JavaScript array of objects by object key, reactively

Tags: arrays, vue.js, key

```
let arr = [{id:'one',val:1},{id:'two',val:2}]
for( let ii of arr ) {
    if( ii.hasOwnProperty('id') ) arr[ii.id] = ii
}
```

The above code allows us to access the array by the id key, e.g.
`arr['one'] //{id:'one', val:1}`.

But the code needs to re-run after mutating the array by adding or deleting items. Is there a way of making the mutation automatic/reactive using JavaScript or Vue?

Comment: The question lacks the context. It's unknown what's your case exactly and what's Vue version, which is relevant. "arr['one']" - arrays have indexes, not string keys. Probably that's the problem here

Comment: for Vue.js you can use the computed property.

Comment: for pure JavaScript you can use a Proxy to realize a reactive object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### A pure js solution using the `Proxy` API, I think it's what you want.

> But why do you use `id` as a key to add the original array? It is not iterable when using `for` to loop the array. That's weird and pointless, in my opinion.

```js
const reactiveCallback = (arr) => {
  for(const item of arr) {
    if(item.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
      arr[item.id] = item
    }
  }
  console.log(`new arr =`, arr)
}

const arr = [{id:'one', val:1}, {id:'two', val:2}]

const proxy = new Proxy(arr, {
  get: function (target, prop, receiver) {
    // delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      reactiveCallback(arr)
    }, 0);
    return target[prop];
  },
});

proxy.push({id:'three', val: 3})
proxy.pop()
```

### more meaningful solution

If you want to use `id` as a key of an object instead of the `index` of an array.

```js
const arr = [{id:'one', val:1}, {id:'two', val:2}]
let arrObj = {}
const reactiveCallback = (arr) => {
  arrObj = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item;
    return obj;
  }, {})
  console.log(`new arr copy object =`, arrObj)
}

const proxy = new Proxy(arr, {
  get: function (target, prop, receiver) {
    // delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      reactiveCallback(arr)
    }, 0);
    return target[prop];
  },
});

proxy.push({id:'three', val: 3})
proxy.pop()
```

Comment: random access to array element via `arr['two']` instead of `arr.find( el => el.id = 'two' )` is the idea. This keeps the iterable array of objects while getting direct access to object items with known id/key

Comment: Why did you wrap `reactiveCallback` in a delay, 0? If the `setTimeout` is removed, arr['one'] works; otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: It's better to use a new copy of the original array instead of mixing them, it's best practice to keep all items in the array of the same type.

Comment: Like this `const arrObj = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {obj[item.id] = item; return obj;}, {})`, you will get a new object of the original array's copy.

Comment: The reason why use a `setTimeout` is that we need a delay before accessing the updated array data. We had to wait until the `return` worked.

Comment: So, `arrObj['three']` should then work the same as `proxy['three']` if you comment the `proxy.pop()`. Would you please try it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, but if you want to learn something in more depth you should try it yourself. Or, show me your code.